# ¿Cómo definir correctamente una variable?

Tags: php, html, sql, variables

Desde que añadi la funcion `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Me sale el siguiente error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: acumulado in
>   C:\AppServ\www\sisadmin\modulos\compras\reportes\reporte_articulos_abc_pc.php
>   on line 144

el cual hace referencia a la variable $acumulado

```
define('PAGE_TITLE', 'Gesti&oacute;n de Compras');
define('MOD_TITLE', 'Gesti&oacute;n de Compras :: Reporte Art&iacute;culos por M&eacute;todo ABC Por Precio/Cantidad');

if ($_POST['excel'] == 'SI') {
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=REPORTE_ARTICULOS_POR_METODO_ABC_POR_PRECIO_CANTIDAD_" . date('d.m.Y') . "_" . date('h.i.s') . ".xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
}

$mysqli = new dbMysqli;

function Retornar_Total($sql) {
    global $mysqli;
    $total = 0;

    $res = $mysqli->query($sql);

    while ($dato = $res->fetch_object()) {
        $total += $dato->Precio * $dato->cantidad_existente;
    }

    return $total;
}

function Retornar_Nombre_Deposito($id) {
    global $mysqli;

    $sql = "SELECT nombre FROM obrasdeposito WHERE id = '$id'";
    $res = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $obj = $res->fetch_object();

    return $obj->nombre;
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo PAGE_TITLE ?></title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
        <?php if ($_POST['excel'] == 'NO') { ?>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../../estilo/styles.css" />
        <style type="text/css">
            .legend { width: 2%; border: 1px solid #999; text-align: center; padding: 2px; display: inline-block; }
            .right { text-align: right !important; }
        </style>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <style type="text/css"><?php require_once('../../../estilo/styles.css') ?></style>
        <?php } ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if ($_POST['excel'] == 'NO') { ?>
        <table class="table-title">
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo MOD_TITLE ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="table-buttons">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Cerrar" onClick="self.close()" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="table-fields">
            <tr>
                <td width="10%"><strong>Dep&oacute;sito</strong></td>
                <td width="90%"><?php echo Retornar_Nombre_Deposito($_POST['deposito']) ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="10%"><strong>Legenda</strong></td>
                <td width="90%">
                    <span class="legend" style="background-color:#BEF781">A</span>
                    <span class="legend" style="background-color:#F3E2A9">B</span>
                    <span class="legend" style="background-color:#FA5882">C</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php } ?>
        <table class="table-list">
            <thead>
                <tr> 
                    <td>C&oacute;digo Art&iacute;culo</td>
                    <td>Nombre Art&iacute;culo</td>
                    <td>Stock Actual * Precio</td>
                    <td>Unidad</td>
                    <td>%</td>
                    <td>Acumulado</td>
                    <td>Categor&iacute;a</td> 
                    <td>Stock Actual</td>
                    <td>Precio</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                $sql = "SELECT 
                            res.codigoArticulo, 
                            res.articulo, 
                            res.unidad, 
                            res.Precio, 
                            res.cantidad_existente 
                        FROM
                            (
                                SELECT 
                                    stp.cod_articulo as codigoArticulo,
                                    art.nombre as articulo,
                                    stp.stock as cantidad_existente,
                                    art.unidad as unidad,
                                    IFNULL(ROUND((
                                        SELECT dp.precio
                                        FROM detalle_pedidos as dp
                                        INNER JOIN pedidos p ON p.num_pedido = dp.num_pedido
                                        WHERE p.estado != 'ANULADA' AND dp.cod_articulo = stp.cod_articulo
                                        ORDER BY dp.num_pedido DESC
                                        LIMIT 1
                                    ), 2), 0) as Precio
                                FROM
                                    stock_tareaprogramada as stp
                                INNER JOIN 
                                    articulos as art ON stp.cod_articulo = art.cod_articulo 
                                WHERE
                                    stp.deposito_id = '{$_POST['deposito']}'
                                    AND stp.cod_articulo = art.cod_articulo
                                    AND stp.stock > 0
                                    AND art.estado != 'BAJA'
                                    AND art.stockeable = 'SI'
                            ) as res
                        ORDER BY res.Precio * res.cantidad_existente DESC";

                $res = $mysqli->query($sql);

                if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
                    $total = Retornar_Total($sql);

                    while ($dato = $res->fetch_object()) {
                        $cantidadPorPrecio = $dato->cantidad_existente * $dato->Precio;
                        $porcentaje = ($cantidadPorPrecio * 100) / $total;
                        $acumulado = $acumulado + $porcentaje;

                        if ($acumulado < 80 ) {
                            $categoria = "A";
                            $bgcolor = "#BEF781";
                        } elseif ($acumulado < 95 ) {
                            $categoria = "B";
                            $bgcolor = "#F3E2A9";
                        } else {
                            $categoria = "C";
                            $bgcolor = "#FA5882";
                        }
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo "[" . $dato->codigoArticulo. "]" ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $dato->articulo ?></td>
                            <td class="right"><?php echo number_format($cantidadPorPrecio, 2, ",", ".") ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $dato->unidad ?></td>
                            <td class="right"><?php echo "%" . number_format($porcentaje, 2, ',' , ".") ?></td>    
                            <td class="right"><?php echo "%" . number_format($acumulado, 2, ',' , '.') ?></td>
                            <td bgcolor="<?php echo $bgcolor ?>"><?php echo $categoria ?></td>
                            <td class="right"><?php echo number_format($dato->cantidad_existente, 2, ",", ".") ?></td>
                            <td class="right"><?php echo number_format($dato->Precio, 2, ",", ".") ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?
                    }
```

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y agrega toda la informacion en la pregunta, no en comentarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que, la primera vez que entra al `while` pides a tu variable `$acumulado` se sume con `$porcentaje` pero en el primer ciclo acumulado no existe.

```
while ($dato = $res->fetch_object()) {
   $cantidadPorPrecio = $dato->cantidad_existente * $dato->Precio;
   $porcentaje = ($cantidadPorPrecio * 100) / $total;
   $acumulado = $acumulado + $porcentaje;
   ...
 }
```

Lo puedes solucionar declarando `$acumulado` fuera del `while`

```
$acumulado = 0;
while ($dato = $res->fetch_object()) {
   $cantidadPorPrecio = $dato->cantidad_existente * $dato->Precio;
   $porcentaje = ($cantidadPorPrecio * 100) / $total;
   $acumulado = $acumulado + $porcentaje;
   ...
 }
```

El agregar  `error_reporting(E_ALL);` te estará reportando todo lo que PHP encuentre mal en tu código, aunque este error de `$acumulado` es informativo y no merma la ejecución de la aplicación, es molesto ver el mensaje, peor aún si activaste la función en un ambiente de producción.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Alberto!